# How to import indicator in script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to use the Williams alligator indicator with my strategy but i don't know how to add it to my script . I am new to tradingview so i don't know much ,is there any option to import the library or indicator  in my script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only import libraries.

If you want to use another indicator in your code, you must copy&paste its code into your own indicator's code.

Comment: ,i wanted to use the William alligator indicator in my strategy . How can i do it?